# Dynamically choose what DAO to use

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two DAO classes. One is AdminDAO and the other is CustomerDAO. I am using Spring boot and have autowired both DAOs.

My authentication class should take the either the Admin Class or the Customer class and choose the correct autowired DAO. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
package com.capstone.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.capstone.dao.AdminDAO;
import com.capstone.dao.CustomerDAO;

public class Authentication<T> implements AuthenticationInterface{

    private T currentUser = null;
    
    @Autowired
    AdminDAO adminDao;
    
    @Autowired
    CustomerDAO customerDao;
    
    @Override
    public boolean authenticate(String userName, String password) {
        //if I pass a customer it should use customerDao 
        
        //if I pass an admin it should use the adminDao
        
        //some method implementation
        
        return false;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void logout() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    public T getCurrentUser() {
        return currentUser;
    }

    public void setCurrentUser(T currentUser) {
        this.currentUser = currentUser;
    }


}
```

I believe writing the  after the Authentication class makes it a generic?

Comment: A few notes: It is not customary in Java to "tag" types with names like `Interface`; we know it's an interface because it's an interface. You seem to be mixing "authentication" in the sense of "a value representing a principal" and "a service authenticating users" here, and the mixing of concerns will cause headaches. If you're writing a "generic service", then usually you'll only pass in a single DAO type. Finally, field injection like this is a Bad Pattern; just use regular `final` fields and pass the values in a constructor (you don't even need `@Autowired` then!).

Comment: Simply you can using if-else cause in user role to do your logical, but It would be better if you are using interface and create something like DAO factory class, In there, create a function to return the interface of created concrete class base on the user role

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to implement that. It pretty much depends on how do you want to store the data in the database.
For example, you might have one single table in the database that stores the information about all the users in the system in addition you could have some flag "isAdmin" which is stored as a column in the table (real systems usually don't work like this, but I understand this is for educational purposes).
So you should end up with something like this:

```
userName | password | isAdmin
-----------------------------
admin    |  123456  |  true
jane     |  qwerty  |  false
jack     |  654321  |  false
-----------------------------
```

With this representation you could create a method that would, given the user name and password, check whether the user is admin or not and return some boolean flag. This method could be implemented in a DAO:

```
public interface MyDao {
    boolean isAdmin(String user, String password); // the implementation depends on the actual database, technology (spring data, jpa, raw jdbc, etc)
}
```

Then your `authenticate` method becomes something like this:

```
public boolean authenticate(String userName, String password) {
        boolean isAdmin = myDao.isAdmin(userName, password); 
        if(isAdmin) {
           // use adminDao for authentication
        }
        else {
           // user customerDao for authentication
        }
    }
```

**Now I would like to emphasize that this is a bad design** for real products, but it ok to me for exercises.

If you want to know more about how this can be implemented in real products, Read about the differences about Authentication and Authorization, understand what is the Principal, the concept of Credentials (you'll realize that actually admin is really similar to the regular user but with extra credentials).

In addition, after you understand all this, since you're already using Spring - read about Spring Security - it offers the "ready to go-for-real-work" design of these components + a lot of the code will be already implemented for you.